# What is fast path, slow path, hot path

Tags: go

I've been reading Go source code for a while , there are three terms which is `fast path`,`slow path`, `hot path` comes up a lot.

- fast path : https://cs.opensource.google/search?q=%22fast%20path%22&ss=go%2Fgo
- slow path : https://cs.opensource.google/search?q=%22slow%20path%22&ss=go%2Fgo
- hot path : https://cs.opensource.google/search?q=%22hot%20path%22&ss=go%2Fgo

So, my question is, what exactly is `fast path`,`slow path`, `hot path` ? Are these terms unique to Go ?

Comment: These are not anything specific to go, it’s just explaining some of the logic in the code.

Comment: you can always use the online browser to search for something and share the results https://cs.opensource.google/search?q=%22fast%20path%22&sq=&ss=go%2Fgo

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks, I've replaced images with search result links

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fast path is a path that's fast (i.e. does less work), and a slow path is a path that's slow (i.e. does more work). For example, when adding a value to a hashmap, just sticking the value into an empty bucket is the fast path, while increasing the number of buckets, copying all of the values to their new locations, *then* inserting the new value is the slow path. When adding floating point numbers, the case where one of them is a denormal is a slow path, many times slower than the path for ordinary numbers. The notion of "paths" indicates that either one could happen for a given function, depending on circumstances or on the value provided; it's not a *choice* of being fast or slow.

A "hot" path is one that's taken most of the time, while a "cold" path is one that's taken only rarely. Hot paths are good targets for optimization, because they are where a program spends most of its time. Happiness occurs when the hot path is also the fast path, and the slow paths are also cold.

None of this is specific to Go; it's common terminology in computing.

Comment: The advantage of fast paths is: - Many calls bypass reflection altogether